How to convert a value to base 16 or base 2 or decimal in groovy?
I need to implement a function toBase(a,b) where 'b' is the value which needs to be converted to the base 'a' in groovy. Need help on this function.


A string that contains digits and letters from 0 to Z, which covers base systems up to base 36.

The while loop continuously divides b by a, calculating the remainder and using that to get the corresponding digit from digits. The process continues until b becomes zero.

The result is built in reverse by prepending each digit to the result string.


def toBase(a, b) {
    if (a < 2 || a > 36) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Base must be between 2 and 36")
    }

    String digits = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    def result = ""
    
    while (b > 0) {
        int remainder = b % a
        result = digits[remainder] + result
        b = b.intdiv(a)
    }
    
    return result == "" ? "0" : result
}

println toBase(2, 255)   // Binary representation of 255 -> 11111111
println toBase(16, 255)  // Hexadecimal representation of 255 -> FF

